# Was the glowing of Sorrento's avatar's eyes a reference to Superman's heat vision?

Tags: reference, ready-player-one

Why were Sorrento's avatar's eyes glowing yellow when he first sees Irock then turn blue after he sighs in *Ready Player One*? Was this a reference to Superman's heat vision? I don't get it. Does his Clark Kent looking avatar have those powers?

Comment: why would it be related to Superman? There's no indication of that.

Answer (score 4):

## Probably not

Sorrento's avatar's eye glow blue in their normal state...

[image]

..but when he get's angry, exited or has some other negative emotion, they change to a yellow/red glow.

[image]

This is probably to indicate some "eyes are the windows of the soul" type of thing.

> Was this a reference to Superman's heat vision? Does his Clark Kent looking avatar have those powers?

There's no indication that the avatar has *any* powers other than significant strength and I always thought the avatar was more "Mafia Don" based than "Clark Kent".

Comment: I can't deny your answer, but the pictures don't seem to be proof of your answer. In the second picture, the red glow (from whatever he is holding) is all over his face, and logically his eyes as well. I still identify his pupils as the same blue, but the entire eyeball (eye white + pupil) has a red shine to it (if you zoom in on the picture, you can clearly see that the pupils are still bright blue)

Comment: If you review the movie you can see this happening. I just chose two images that demostrate the difference.